# Две ForeignKey-привязки в модели django

Tags: python, django, model, foreign-key, django-model

Можно и эффективно ли писать так 2 ForeignKey привязку к одной модели, к примеру так:

```
class User(models.Model):...


class PrivateMessage(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE)
    to_user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE)
```

Если нет, то как посоветуете реализовать привязку к двум объектам модели?

Comment: можешь, только для каждой нужно указать свой(уникальный) `related_name`

Comment: @AndreyMaslov а зачем?) можно и без него

Comment: без него можно, но только один раз. если я правильно помню, то для каждой связки `ForeignKey` `django` создает обратную связь и при двух `ForeignKey` на одну и ту же таблицу, хотя бы для одного нужно указать `related_name`.